# Element on hover scaled beyond the parent size

Tags: css, animation, css-position, scale

Trying to scale a card beyond the size of its parent and other divs without success.

Once you hover a card, this should scale up taking part of the height of the screen. The results that i got so far or make a mess having the card scaled in a fix position and being very unstable or having a good escalation but not full visible.

Any idea how to tackle this?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mgm2000/pen/WNJErQz)

```
.iZNdlS {
z-index: 200;
position: relative;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 4px;
background-origin: border-box;
background-clip: content-box, border-box;
cursor: pointer;
flex-shrink: 0;
min-width: 300px;
max-width: 300px;
min-height: 490px;
max-height: 490px;
transition: transform 0.7s ease 0s;
transform-origin: center top 0px;
```

}

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: i posted the cards styles although there are many other elements involved in the issue as you can see in the code in the external link. IMHO to write all of that here doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Please go over your question before you post it, as you might catch mistakes that would have otherwise confused people trying to answer your question. While I was trying to read the question, I found it very unclear and I even found parts of the sentence completely missing. But from what I understand you are trying to make a card scale to a size greater than its parent element. If this is the case the code is below.

```css
body {

  margin: 0;
  
}

.container {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.card {

  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .2s;
  
}

.card:hover {

  transform: scale(1.3);
  
}

.image {

  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="card">
      <image src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-45201.jpg&fm=jpg" class="image" \>
      <span>Cat</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <image src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-45201.jpg&fm=jpg" class="image" \>
      <span>Cat</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="card">
      <image src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-45201.jpg&fm=jpg" class="image" \>
      <span>Cat</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <image src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-45201.jpg&fm=jpg" class="image" \>
      <span>Cat</span>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

I think the reason your scale isn't working is because the parent has `overflow: hidden` which will make any content beyond the parents border disappear, however I don't know if this is the case because your CSS is ridiculously long and I don't have time to go through every line of code to check for a property. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Apulum. You nailed it. Thanks a lot. It was the overflow. ` display: inline-block;`  looks like not necessary. Not sure if there is a good explanation to implement it.
Nevertheless the first card is being cut on the left side. I had there a menu and the result is not good. I gonna try to find a solution to that too. If you come up with something.. please, let me know. I updated my codepen. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help, I don't understand the problem your describing, your saying you have a menu to the left of the cards? If you could send me the full project in codepen I will try to make a replica of what you want and then you could edit and style it the way you want. However I am not going to try to edit the original code because it is too long. If you could give me the bounty soon it would be appreciated because I am trying to unlock things on stack overflow, have been on the grind if you know what I mean. If of course the answer is what your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scale only image when hovering over the card:

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__image-holder">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_51923601496_2649a4c0ce_320_240_nofilter.jpg" alt="my-cat">
  </div>
  
  <div class="card__content">
   <h3>My Cat</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit ut repellendus veniam, etcorrupti iusto sequi repellat pariatur commodi est iure repudiandae?</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.card__image-holder {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card__image-holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.card__content {
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
}

.card:hover .card__image-holder img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

The key is to add wrapper around image and **overflow: hidden;** to that wrapper, so image don't scale outside the wrapper, than apply transform of image on card hover.

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g7256y1a/1/

Comment: Thanks Milan. I like the animation that you made although my goal was to scale the whole card. As you can see it's been hidden behind many other elements

Answer (score 1):

From what i've seen in your codePen, the problem you're facing that cuts the first container is because of the `margin-left: 100px` on the `.kjqkcL` class.

It should work fine if you change it to `padding-left: 100px` instead.

Answer (score -1):

dude, your code is so messy. why are there 5 classes for each element? OMG. And here you didn't even post on-hover style.

anyway, I checked your code and finally found it. you can do that by making the card `z-index` **on hover** higher than its parent. I tried `100` but didn't work. then I tried `1000` and it worked.

```
.iZNdlS:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
    z-index: 1000;
  }
```

also, your scale is too much. the cards on the edges need enough space otherwise they will be cropped. to solve that, **reduce** the `scale` and give parents enough `padding` to show cards on the edges.

Comment: Hi Will. Thanks for your response and sorry for the mess. It's the output of the web app based on react. I wanted to keep the whole page just in case that other problems come with other elements.
Your css doesnt fix the problem. The card is cut. Thanks anyway
PS. i havent downvoted

Comment: @Zenit thanks for the replay. I understand now and sorry for my judgment. According to your given code, my solution work. I just checked your codepen and I saw that you added `z-index: 1000;` and each card on hover is above all other elements. if the card on the edges is what you mean by still cut, then read my answer again, I mentioned that too. good luck.